# batch: question mark wildcard not working with dots

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that tries to find duplicate videos by title. I have the title extrapolated from the filename and I am trying to search for other files beginning with the same name using the `?` wildcard in between keywords:

`for /r %%i in ("%string%*") do set /a count+=1`

where `%string` has a format of `The?Title?S01E01` so I am searching with `"The?Title?S01E01*"` which works well when the words are separated with spaces etc but when the separators are dots it fails. How do I overcome this? I've had to add a separate handler for this in every script I've ever done.

Comment: The last dot in a file name separates the base name from the extension. Is there a file extension in your names? perhaps you need `The?Title?S01E01*.*`...

Comment: yes there are several different extension possibilities. I tried this `The?Title?S01E01*.*` method but could not get a better result (still nothing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `for` (like `dir` or other internal commands too) becomes confused by the period `.` as it denotes the separator of the file name extension from the base name.

There is the external command [`where`](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) (since Windows Vista, I think), which does a slightly different handling of wild-cards like `?` and `*`, which appears to be suitable for your task:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('where /R "." "The?Title?S01E01*"') do set /A "count+=1"
```

In the above code, `where` is producing the list of matching files in the current directory and below, which is then captured and parsed by a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to make each item available in variable `%%i`.

To prevent `where` to display an error message in case no files are found, do this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('where /R "." "The?Title?S01E01*" 2^> nul') do set /A "count+=1"
```

Note the escaped redirection `^>`, which is necessary to not to be tried to be executed on `for /F`.

---

If you want to search for matching files in the current directory only rather than the full tree, change the command line to this (note the prefix `.:`):

```cmd
where ".:The?Title?S01E01*"
```

Comment: It is very bizarre how WHERE treats wildcards differently than every other standard Windows command that I am aware of.

Comment: Yes, it is, @dbenham; `where`, `replace` and `forfiles` behave similar (at least for the example in this thread); `robocopy` seems to behave similar to internal commands for the example at hand; it is really confusing. Once I find the time, I will do extensive testing on wildcards...

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of the `?` is wrong. It does not match simply any single character. Rather it matches any character *except* `.`. If there is no character to match (at end of name, or before a `.`), then `?` will match "nothing" without failure.

I describe this behavior at [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) over on SuperUser.

This behavior is consistent for almost all Windows standard commands. But there is at least one exception, the `where` command, as [pointed out by aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149831/1012053). His `where` solution is probably the simplest solution to your problem.

A significantly more complicated alternative is to use FINDSTR with an appropriately derived regex to refine your result. The initial FOR search would substiture `*` for all `?` in the string.

```
set "string2=%string:.=\.%"
set "string2=%string2:?=.%"
set "string2=%string2:*=.*%"
set "string2=%string2:^=\^%"
set "string2=%string2:$=\$%"
for /r %%i in ("%string:?=*%*") do echo %%~nxi|findstr /ric:"^%string2%" >nul && set /a count+=1
```